# Reconstruction of Enright Test using OpenVDB

Tags: c++, graphics, voxel, openvdb

I want to recreate the Enright Test results with OpenVDB as mentioned in the [article](http://www.museth.org/Ken/OpenVDB_files/Museth_TOG13.pdf) by Ken Museth.

After setting up OpenVDB I've Created the sphere similarly to the way it was described in the OpenVDB test [git](https://github.com/dreamworksanimation/openvdb/blob/master/openvdb/unittest/util.h).

I have recieved results which are very different than the results shown in the article.

my code is shown below:

```
openvdb::GridCPtrVec SphereTest(){
openvdb::GridCPtrVec GridVec;

float fGridSize = 512;

int iGridSize = 512;

double w = 1;

openvdb::Vec3f centerEnright(0.35*fGridSize, 0.35*fGridSize, 0.35*fGridSize);

openvdb::FloatGrid::Ptr grid(new openvdb::FloatGrid());

grid->setGridClass(openvdb::GridClass::GRID_LEVEL_SET);

auto tree = grid->treePtr();

auto outside = 5 * w;

auto inside = -outside;

for (int i = 0; i < iGridSize; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < iGridSize; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < iGridSize; k++)
        {
            openvdb::Coord coord(i, j, k);
            const openvdb::Vec3f p = grid->transform().indexToWorld(coord);
            const float dist = float((p - centerEnright).length() - (0.15*fGridSize));
            auto aDist = abs(dist);

            if (aDist < outside)
            {
                if (dist>0)
                    tree->setValue(coord, dist);
                else
                    tree->setValue(coord, dist);
            }
            else
            {
                if (dist>outside)
                    tree->setValueOff(coord, outside);
                else
                    tree->setValueOff(coord, inside);
            }


        }
    }
}

std::cout << "Active Voxels MV: " << grid->activeVoxelCount() / 1000000.0 << "\n";

double mem = MemInfo::virtualMemUsedByMe();

std::cout << "Memory MB: " << mem / 1000000.0 << "\n";

openvdb::tools::pruneLevelSet(grid->tree());

std::cout << "Active Voxels MV: " << grid->activeVoxelCount() / 1000000.0 << "\n";

double lastmem=mem;

mem = MemInfo::virtualMemUsedByMe();

std::cout << "Memory MB: " << (mem-lastmem) / 1000000.0 << "\n";

GridVec.push_back(grid);}
```

my results are as follows :

Active Voxels MV: 0.742089

Memory MB: 617.325

after

Active Voxels MV: 0.742089

Memory MB: 56.234

and as one can see it is **ten folds bigger** from the results in the article.

Results can be seen in Tables II ,III and IV in the article referring to the 512^3 gridsize , with the [6,5,4,3] tree branching. I've reached the almost the same number of active voxels(Table III) , but with significant additional memory consumption table(IV), while the results of Table II are very confusing. am I missing something? or doing something wrong , maybe not activating some kind of compression, or bit quantization as the article states.

also when looking at the generated grid using the viewer it shows a perfect rounded sphere(not voxelized in the boolean manner) , which is what I'm going for.

any thoughts?

thank you